# Using R's "which" function in Rcpp, not returning values

Tags: rcpp

I've written an Rcpp function to call R's which function to check for equality. It compiles fine but it appears that it is only returning values for the first item in a vector: `mywhich(samplevector, samplevector[1])` returns a value, `mywhich(samplevector, samplevector[2])` returns `numeric(0)`.

The code of the function is below, it only needs to run on Numeric and Integer Vectors

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP mywhich(SEXP x, SEXP y) {

  //For each supported type, turn it into the 'real' type and
  //perform the operation. We can use TYPEOF to check the type.
  switch(TYPEOF(x)){
  case REALSXP: { 
   Environment base("package:base"); 
   Function f("which");
   NumericVector answer = f(as<NumericVector>(y) == as<NumericVector>(x));
   return wrap(answer);
}
  case INTSXP: { 
    Environment base("package:base"); 
    Function f("which");
    IntegerVector answer = f(as<IntegerVector>(y) == as<IntegerVector>(x));
    return wrap(answer);
  }
  default: {
    stop("Only integer and numeric vectors are supported");
  }
  }}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `<long vector> == <short vector>` in R, the short vector gets recycled to match the long vector's length. This does not happen in Rcpp! In your case, you want to do `<vector> == <single element vector>`, which can be done in Rcpp with `<vector> == <double/int/...>`. This means you have to select the 0-Element from the single element vector. In your code:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP mywhich(SEXP x, SEXP y) {

  //For each supported type, turn it into the 'real' type and
  //perform the operation. We can use TYPEOF to check the type.
  switch(TYPEOF(x)){
  case REALSXP: { 
   Environment base("package:base"); 
   Function f("which");
   NumericVector answer = f(as<NumericVector>(y)(0) == as<NumericVector>(x));
   //                                           ^^^
   return wrap(answer);
}
  case INTSXP: { 
    Environment base("package:base"); 
    Function f("which");
    IntegerVector answer = f(as<IntegerVector>(y)(0) == as<IntegerVector>(x));
    //                                           ^^^
    return wrap(answer);
  }
  default: {
    stop("Only integer and numeric vectors are supported");
  }
  }}
```

BTW, I am not convinced that you need `which` from R to find the indices in a `LogicalVector` that are `true`.